# gcc inline assembler incbin doesn't seem to use -I argument

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

I converted a project that builds fine with gcc 2017.3 eabi-none (raw metal, x86_x64 cross compile for ARM A7, RM compiler) to gcc 2019.3 raw metal Cortex-A compiler. It works well but gets to one strange problem.

The project has a makefile that builds a set of small test components, laid out into a tree:

```
project/test/drivertype1/foo.c
project/test/drivertype2/bar.c
etc.
```

The make working directory is `project/`. Inside `foo.c`, there are some included binary files via inline assembly `.incbin` directive. The data is in a subdirectory:

```
project/test/drivertype1/data/input.bin
```

This relative path is split. The command line has `-Itest/drivertype1` - the left side of the relative path - and the source code has the right side:

```
__asm__ (
    "test_message:\n"
    "    .incbin \"data/input.bin\"\n"
    "test_message_end:"
)
```

This results in a build error:

```
Assembler messages:
22: Error: file not found: data/input.bin
```

I reproduce this by pulling the command out of the makefile log and running it by hand.

If I run the command with working directory set to `project/` like make does, the error reproduces. If I instead run it from `project/test/drivertype1/`, then it builds.

When run from `project`, I've tried specifying the full path (e.g., `-I/home/user/.../project/test/drivertype1`) and it does not work. And I've tried other similar tests with relative paths.

My conclusion is that `-I` is not used with `.incbin` unlike what the man says.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a proper answer, and too large for a comment. This seems to work with GCC (x86 and x86-64 Linux targets).

In the project directory I create the directory path `testdir/data` with `mkdir -p testdir/data`. I then create an empty file called `testdir/data/input.bin`. I create a *C* program called `test.c` in the current directory that contains:

```
int main()
{
    __asm__ (
        "test_message:\n"
        "    .incbin \"data/input.bin\"\n"
        "test_message_end:"
    );
}
```

I then assemble this with `gcc test.c -o test` and it fails as expected (the way yours does). If I use `gcc test.c -Itestdir/ -o test`, the `.incbin` directive was able to find the file and compile successfully.

If this doesn't work for you then I can only assume there is a problem with GCC for your target; there is some problem that prevents `-I` from being passed properly to GCC in your make file; or the path specified by `-I` isn't relative to the directory you think GCC was run from.

---

AFAIK paths are relative to the directory where GCC is run from, not the directory where the `.c` file is. If your `.c` file is `project/test/drivertype1/foo.c` and you compile with GCC from the `project` directory then your command line would have to use `-Itest/drivertype1`. If you are *in* the `project` directory something like this *should* work:

```
gcc -Itest/drivertype1 test/drivertype1/foo.c
```

Comment: Yup, `gcc -v` confirms that `-I` args are passed on to `as` when its assembling the output of the main `cc1` compiler that goes from C to asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I suspect what is likely going on is that he's running GCC (via a makefile) from one directory to compile a C file in another directory and the path of `data` is not relative to where he thinks it is. Although it doesn't quite explain why an absolute path would fail unless he typed it incorrectly. Beyond that some strange bug in GCC that is specific to some targets.

Comment: The working directory is `project` where as the C file is in `drivertype1`. I expected -I to work, and it seemed to have worked before I changed compilers. Today I discovered `-Wa,-Itest/drivertype1` works and am going forward with that.